# Writing your own version control system using a database?

Tags: c#, database-design, database-schema

I'd like to know which would be the best way to approach this problem:

1. A user writes an article and presses save. (saved to the database)
2. A user edits the previous article and presses save. (like git commit)
3. Repeat

At each stage the user edits the article, I want to show the user the changes (additions and subtractions) that have been made during each commit.

I thought of two ways of doing this:

1. Keep all iterations of the article contents saved in the database. Aka create a new row for each save, containing the entirety of the article contents. Then, compare the files in the backend by checking for differences.

   ```
   +-----------+---------+----------------------------+
   | ArticleID | Version |            Body            |
   +-----------+---------+----------------------------+
   |         1 |       3 | This is a random article.  |
   |         1 |       2 | This is a random article   |
   |         1 |       1 | a random article           |
   +-----------+---------+----------------------------+
   ```
2. OR record all changes to the article by storing it like below, and then when the user wants to see the differences between version 1 and 2, get version 1 and append the changes made

   ```
   +-----------+---------+-------------------+-------------------+---+
   | ArticleID | Version | CharacterPosition |         +         | - |
   +-----------+---------+-------------------+-------------------+---+
   |         1 |       3 |                24 | .                 |   |
   |         1 |       2 |                 0 | This is           |   |
   |         1 |       1 |                 0 | a random article  |   |
   +-----------+---------+-------------------+-------------------+---+
   ```

Comment: Well, cvs, svn, git, tfs, ... use the differential apprach. What does this tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest option 1. If you use option two you'll get into trouble when someome adds or removes characters from different positions. Besides it would give  some coding difficulties if you want to see whats the difference with three versions back.